# Trouble while setting up an EJS project

Tags: javascript, html, typeerror, ejs

Trying to build a to do list app using ejs and I've run into a error:

Here is the error code

throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))
^

TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a string
at Function.use (/home/revolverclyde/Web_Development/to-do-list/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:458:13)
at Function. (/home/revolverclyde/Web_Development/to-do-list/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:220:21)
at Array.forEach ()
at Function.use (/home/revolverclyde/Web_Development/to-do-list/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:217:7)
at Object. (/home/revolverclyde/Web_Development/to-do-list/app.js:8:5)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)

**Here is the content of my app.js file**

```
 const express = require("express");
    const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    const {Router} = require("express");
    
    const app = express();
    
    app.use(app,Router);

    
    app.use("view engine", "ejs");
    
    app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    
        var today = new Date();
        var currentDay = today.getDay();
        var day = "";
    
        if (today.getDay() === 6 || today.getDay() === 0){
            day = "Weekend";
    
        } else {
            day = "Weekday"
        }
    
        res.render("list", {kindofday: day})
    });
    
    app.listen(3000, function(){
        console.log("Server started on port 3000")
    })
```

**Here is the content of my list.ejs file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>To Do list</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>It's <%=kindofday%></h1>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your help and your time.

Comment: What is `routes`? The source code you've pasted has no indication of why `routes.initialize` would be a thing.

Comment: A typo/left over from a different fix attempt. It has been removed. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to take requests from your user on this route

```
https://{yourDomainName}/api
```

For this you want to handle get, put, post, delete methods in your server
So, you have to write code for all of these methods separately like,

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();    

app.get("/api", () => {
    ... 
})

app.post("/api", () => {
    ... 
})

app.put("/api", () => {
    ... 
})

app.delete("/api", () => {
    ... 
})
```

You can see that we are writing the same code again and again.
So, express has the router class which can handle these requests like this

```
... 

const router = express.Router();

router
    .route("/api");
    .get( ... )
    .post( ... )
    .put( ... )
    .delete( ... )
```

This is one use case of router
Another one is with using sub routes in the same route. like you want to have some more routes in "api/"

so you write

```
...    

router.get("/cat", () => {
   ...
})    

app.use("/api", router)

...
```

now on "/api/cat" someone can request for something. you can do that many more times with other sub routes on "/api/{someOtherRoute}"

But in your app you are using router without any need. And also you are using

```
 app.use(app, router);
```

express cannot be used in its own methods. this might be the reason your app is crashing

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code, it helps your answer be more clear.

Comment: Thanks. I've removed it, but there is a new error now.

Comment: I've edited the post to include the new error.